# Using a variable as the URL in getJSON jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I am creating a weather app using jquery. The issue that I am having is in my getJSON I would like to use a variable that I have created using your current latitude and longitude coordinates. The url with my openweather api key loads the json file just fine in the browser but it does not seem to want to work in my getJSON.

Here is my javascript code to display the weather information based off your location.

```
var lat;
var lon;
var jsonURL;

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation);
function GetLocation(location) {
    lat = location.coords.latitude;
    lon = location.coords.longitude;

    jsonURL = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&APPID=example&units=imperial'

}



$("#getWeather").click(function(){
  console.log(jsonURL);
    $.getJSON(jsonURL , function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    items = data;   $("#weather").text(items.main.temp).append('&#8457;');
    });
});
```

Comment: Please remove any sensitive data like your `APPID`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. Look at the Network tab. That would make it clear that your URL is resulting in a 404 error.

Your URL is missing the scheme. It needs `http://` or `https://` on the front.

Browsers will insert `http://` automatically when you type a URL (that is missing the scheme) into the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the api isn't set up to work with requests directly from javascript, frequently you need to write a service on the serverside to communicate with the api, and make your AJAX request to that service instead of directly to the api. Cross-domain AJAX requests are blocked by default in browsers

Answer (score 0):

Actually as mentioned change your url to include:

```
    jsonURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/...'
```

And also make it 'JSOP' format so:

```
        $("#getWeather").click(function() {
          $.getJSON(jsonURL, {
              format: "jsonp"
            })
            .done(function(data) {
              console.log(data);
            }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
              var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
              console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
            });
        });
```

Comment: thanks for that but it doesn't need to be jsonp in this case